# Long delay after logging in but before desktop appears

Tags: 16.04, login-screen

I am a new user to ubuntu 16.04. After entering correct password for logging into desktop screen, just before it appears there is a delay of approximately 10 second where the screen just shows the default wallpaper of desktop. If I log out and log in again there is no problem. I found one probable solution https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1490249 which suggest disabling floppy disk but the solution is way old and also I think my laptop does not consist a floppy disk port.

I have Dell inspiron 3542, 4 GB RAM, Intel I5 @ 1.7Ghz x4 and using X.org X server- nouveau driver(changing to Nvidia did not help!)

If any other detail required please comment.

edit 1:

```
$systemd-analyze blame
Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later
```

edit 2:

```
$systemd-analyze blame
 12.927s dev-sda1.device
      7.691s systemd-udevd.service
      5.165s snapd.service
      3.362s fwupd.service
      2.742s grub-common.service
      2.468s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      2.379s preload.service
      2.333s apport.service
      2.305s ondemand.service
      2.107s irqbalance.service
      2.028s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.887s lightdm.service
      1.752s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      1.650s keyboard-setup.service
      1.320s NetworkManager.service
      1.187s gpu-manager.service
      1.172s systemd-journald.service
      1.116s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.111s accounts-daemon.service
      1.075s dev-hugepages.mount
      1.073s sys-kernel-debug.mount
       987ms dev-mqueue.mount
       616ms apparmor.service
       485ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       442ms setvtrgb.service
       442ms plymouth-start.service
       441ms rsyslog.service
       424ms ufw.service
       335ms console-setup.service
       314ms systemd-logind.service
       303ms upower.service
       301ms alsa-restore.service
       295ms pppd-dns.service
       294ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
       291ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       288ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       282ms systemd-sysctl.service
       281ms thermald.service
       279ms avahi-daemon.service
       268ms polkitd.service
       172ms udisks2.service
       156ms networking.service
       145ms wpa_supplicant.service
       108ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       107ms systemd-rfkill.service
       100ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        55ms dev-loop0.device
        49ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c07aa9cb\x2dd0b5\x2d484f\x2dae1b\x2df78482d
        47ms dev-loop1.device
        33ms plymouth-read-write.service
        32ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        24ms user@1000.service
        24ms snap-chromium-353.mount
        22ms snapd.seeded.service
        18ms colord.service
        17ms snap-core-4830.mount
        17ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        16ms dns-clean.service
        14ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        13ms bluetooth.service
         6ms systemd-random-seed.service
         6ms resolvconf.service
         5ms rtkit-daemon.service
         4ms ureadahead-stop.service
         3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         1ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
         1ms rc-local.service
       475us snapd.socket
```

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) and enter the command `systemd-analyze blame`. Add the top lines of the output to your question so we'll be able to see what is happening at boot time.

Comment: you need to wait a while and then run that command when you first boot. You should have tried it again and then posted the output.

Comment: I tired that too! Output remains the same.

Comment: Does the hard drive seem extremely busy while you're waiting? If it's fast the second time you log in then it sounds like whatever it needs to access is cached. Check your `Startup Applications` when logged in to see what is starting. I believe it can be found in the `Control Centre`, however this may vary depending on which desktop environment you're using. (On Mate it's under `System`.)

Comment: @Ken No, there is no movement of hard drive while waiting. Startup applications are NVIDIA  X server settings, Snap user application autostart helper and SSH key agent. Also I restarted my computer and put up the systemd-analyze blame in terminal and got different result this time(see edit).